# what information in the email header are fake and which are correct?

Tags: email, header, spam

I am receiving too many spam daily and would like to know which information are real and which are faked enable I can put a stop to these nasty spams. Below is one of the email headers. Almost all of them has the domain name edreams.com but the other domains are periodically changing.

If any one has any idea how to stop these nasty spams I would greatly appreciate it.

I would really appreciate any help.
Regards,
John

==============================================================

## one of the email headers from live.com

```
x-store-info: 4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kRwMf1FfZT+Jrph9/aVxAUxzGgJ5DjiUJxnySREhevvw4uL5IjIbrHW1B7dL0Yfq60vttI+eR2ZF/kb+zKkzrLf4D4Xv3E1pZmFPxl97hOfXOZfDUmr1o66E=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 66.195.197.51) smtp.mailfrom=YZThLatTvs582TiJhzLNvqSZEL@edreams.com; dkim=none header.d=news-groupon.ma; x-hmca=none header.id=info@news-groupon.ma
X-SID-PRA: info@news-groupon.ma
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD00
X-Message-Info: 3c21WZ1hAlvD6z4W+Uwvl3qiS53C477VECwbHd8dpu7CzdFaKns7EWfdur6wou4y9E9YzP+cXly0ghczhq0PL7GLrfPApSGKdfnGn4NqAgqLf6qjedk6NTG/hTNlXVfvFWrJluR/80YzrR7vF

+xmqgqs310kwp9D50OG9F92tMXp3fhKlx7OqjsMuLMeJXhXN4mb0iskNfOukuTO1cEso2fCKjOflwj18wwcOqwcYlYEXj8wj6BXWQ==
Received: from regler-nuage.msn.co.uk ([66.195.197.51]) by BAY004-MC2F55.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23008);
     Sat, 4 Jul 2015 14:20:12 -0700
Date: Sat, 4 Jul 2015 23:20:11 -0600
MIME-Version: 1.0
Importance: Low
From: SimplyPMI.co.uk <info@news-groupon.ma>
Subject: RE: {?????my firstname, I removed it?????}; You Deserve Faster Treatment. Get Private Medical Insurance for Less  =?utf-8?Q?=E2=98=91?=
Content-Type: text/html
BCC:
Return-Path: YZThLatTvs582TiJhzLNvqSZEL@edreams.com
Message-ID: <BAY004-MC2F555pneeF0010b4dd@BAY004-MC2F55.hotmail.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 04 Jul 2015 21:20:12.0113 (UTC) FILETIME=[3651CC10:01D0B69F]
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

==============================================================

## end email header

Comment: This is not a programming question.  I have nominated it for migration to https://superuser.com/ with some hesitation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, everything above your local `Received:` header can be trusted, and everything below it is potentially forged.  However, some local mail processors may add headers at the end of the original headers, not at the beginning. Your `X-OriginalArrivalTime:` is probably one of those.

In your particular example, the `From:`, `Return-Path:` and `Message-Id:` look forged, and some others are obviously completely under the sender's control, but not as such "falsified".

Your mail server seems to be running Microsoft Exchange, which in turn means there are more headers you cannot trust, even though they are wrecked by Microsoft, not forged by the spammer.  In particular, Exchange has the nasty habit of munging the MIME structure irrevocably.

As for your final question, there doesn't seem to be anything clearly filterable in the headers.  Given more knowledge of what your regular email looks like, some features could perhaps be postulated.  But on the whole, spammers took a long time to evolve to the point where they often no longer have any obvious static fingerprints in the headers.  (Your first name followed by a comma at the beginning of the Subject seems spammy to me, but if your friends write emails like that, you can't use that, either.)